# Lack of torsion implies 1x = 1

Tags: linear-algebra

This is problem 1 on page 14 of Greub's Linear Algebra text. Show that axioms

1. $kx = 0$ implies $k = 0$ or $x = 0$
2. $1x = x$

are equivalent given all the other usual vector space axioms.

2. $\implies$ 1.: If $kx = 0$, and $k \ne 0$, then 
   \begin{align}
           k^{-1}(k x) = 0 \\      
           (k^{-1}k) x = 0 \\
           1 x = 0 \\
           x = 0
   \end{align}

However, I'm not sure how to proceed to show he reverse direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $1\cdot x=y\neq x$. Then $1\cdot y=y$, because $(1\cdot 1)\cdot x=1\cdot x$. So $1\cdot (x-y)=0$, but $1\neq 0$ and $x-y\neq 0$.

Comment: +1 I should've seen that one. The proof becomes nicer in my opinion if you remove the assumption that $y\neq x$ and prove that $y = x$ (by way of $y-x = 0$). No need to argue by  contradiction.

Comment: Contradiction is not necessary: if $1x=y$, then $0=1x-1x=1(1x)-1x=1y-1x=1(y-x)$. Since $1\ne0$, we conclude $y-x=0$.